# Methods don't chain in Python set

Tags: python, set, method-chaining

I have a Python set consisting of several values and I want to use method chaining like this:

```
>>> f = {1, 2, 3}
>>> g = f.copy().discard(3)
>>> g
>>>
```

but *g* becomes empty. However, it works without chaining:

```
>>> g = f.copy()
>>> g
{1, 2, 3}
>>> g.discard(3)
>>> g
{1, 2}
```

Can somebody explain me this behaviour?

Comment: What brought you to the conclusion that methods do generally chain in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `g = f.copy().discard(3)`, you are storing in g the return value of the method "discard(3)". In this case, it returns nothing, but alters the object. This is why on the second scenario it works.

Answer (score 5):

`discard()` discards an element in the set and returns `None`.

so when you assign

```
g = f.copy().discard(3)
```

this is equivalent to

```
h = f.copy() # now h = f
g = h.discard(3) # g = None; h = {1,2}
```

which leaves you with `g = None`.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead fo `f - {3}`, since `-` on sets is value producing and does not modify its inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It's because [`.discard`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#set.discard) returns `None`.

So when you do `g = f.copy().discard(3)` it creates a copy of `f`, discards the last element, then returns `None`. Since the last thing to be returned is what gets assigned to the variable, `g` ends up with a value of `None`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand that a variable is assigned by the return value of the last method in chain.